# Scanning numbers and adding them to list & scanning answer and adding it to variable

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

The main point is that I want to add numbers to array while the answer is "y". When I input 1 2 3 4 5 6, it only adds last 3 digits to array (so, it's 4 5 6) and sometimes it even skips the character scanning.

The code is following:

```
int numbers1[99];
int i;
int n = 0; 
char answer = 'y'

while (answer == 'y')
    {
        n += 1;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("Insert a number: ");
            scanf("%d", &numbers1[i]);
            printf("Would you like to add more numbers? [Y/N]");
            scanf(" %c", &answer);
        }
    }

    printf("Numbers are following: ");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", numbers1[i]);
    }
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You;'re running the loop....twice.

Comment: Here is a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Just a small pointer, your question does not contain a question or a problem that you have with the code.

Comment: @Dominik Sklyarov The for loop does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the loops is redundant.  That is the `for` loop does not make sense in the context of the `while` loop.

Take into account that you ask the user to enter either `'Y'` or `'N'` in the prompt but compare the variable `answer` with the character `'y'`.

I could suggest the following solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 99 };
    int numbers1[N];

    int n = 0;

    for ( char answer = 'Y'; n < N && answer == 'Y'; n++ )
    {
        printf("Insert a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &numbers1[n]);

        printf("Would you like to add more numbers? [Y/N] ");
        if ( scanf( " %c", &answer ) != 1 ) answer = 'N';
        answer = toupper( ( unsigned char )answer );
    }

    printf( "\nNumbers are following: " );

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( i != 0 ) printf( ", " );
        printf( "%d", numbers1[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Insert a number: 0
Would you like to add more numbers? [Y/N] y
Insert a number: 1
Would you like to add more numbers? [Y/N] 1
Insert a number: 2
Would you like to add more numbers? [Y/N] y
Insert a number: 3
Would you like to add more numbers? [Y/N] y
Insert a number: 4
Would you like to add more numbers? [Y/N] y
Insert a number: 5
Would you like to add more numbers? [Y/N] y
Insert a number: 6
Would you like to add more numbers? [Y/N] y
Insert a number: 7
Would you like to add more numbers? [Y/N] y
Insert a number: 8
Would you like to add more numbers? [Y/N] y
Insert a number: 9
Would you like to add more numbers? [Y/N] n

Numbers are following: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have only one loop. Change your code to

```
while (answer == 'y' && n < 99)    //check also for the array bound.
    {
            printf("Insert a number: ");
            scanf("%d", &numbers1[n++]);  //use 'n' as counter and increment it
            printf("Would you like to add more numbers? [Y/N]");
            scanf(" %c", &answer);
    }
```

Note: Error checking is left for the user to implement.